# Vpn connection problem with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm using private internet access. I'm using ubuntu 14.04 x64 with home disk encryption. I install vpn with this tutorial https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn/

When I try to connect a vpn server by clicking on it nothing happens. After I click it like 10-15 times it connects. When I try to disconnect again I have to click disconnect button for 10-15 times. Is there a easy way to connect-disconnect to vpn? Can I do this in terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also use Ubuntu 14.04 and I have the same problem

You can simply use the openvpn command in terminal.

For example :

```
sudo openvpn --config /path/to/your/config.ovpn
```

If your keys and certificates are not integrated to the config file but are in separated files (ta.key, ca.crt etc ...), make sure that you have not link's problem. If you don't want to modify your links in the config.ovpn, just :

```
cd /path/to/the/config/folder
sudo --config config.ovpn
```

You can launch this command in background and kill the process when you want to stop the VPN. For the moment that's what I do until an update is done.